# i have already connected the ftp server, how can i get this file path?

Tags: android, ftp, urlconnection

```
public void runftpConnect(){
    boolean status = false;
    // Replace your UID & PW here


    status = ftpclient.ftpConnect("192.168.0.109", "root", "s20041644", 21);
    File dir = /*Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();*/
    if (status == true) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection Success");
        localPrintFilesList(dir, "LOCAL FILES");
        Log.d(TAG, "localPrintFilesList");
        //status = ftpclient.ftpUpload(TEMP_FILENAME, TEMP_FILENAME, "/", cntx);

    } else {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection failed", 2000).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection failed");
    }
}
```

so. although i can connect the ftp server, but how can i get the file path?

i tried

```
`String mString = "ftp://192.168.0.109/";

File dir = new File(mString);`
```

but it didn't work.  Is there any way i can get the ftp file path with modify this?

```
File dir = /*Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
File dir = /*Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();*/
```

With this:

```
FTPFile[] dirs = null;
FTPFile[] files = null;
try {
    dirs = client.listDirectories();
    files = client.listFiles();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now you can use FTPFile in foreach to collect information about files or directories. Or you can obtain path to directory you are connected by:

```
try{
    String path = ftpclient.printWorkingDirectory();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTRace();
}
```